# Unable to play Decrypted .ts files

Tags: video, openssl, aes, vlc, m3u8

I have a lot of encrypted .ts files that I'd like to decrypt.
Here's the m3u8 information:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:22
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://b.impartus.com/api/fetchvideo/getVideoKey=3310"
#EXTINF:20.680000......
```

I also have a .key file, here's the hex value of the key 
`ef004a33ab60b5c5669f319072fb45a0`

I use the command `openssl aes-128-cbc -iv 0 -K ef004a33ab60b5c5669f319072fb45a0 -in 000005.ts -out 000005_out.ts` to decrypt the file but am not able to play it.

The output of the above command is `hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length`

Am I doing something wrong as Im not able to view the files in VLC.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I use the command `openssl aes-128-cbc -iv 0 -K ef004a33ab60b5c5669f319072fb45a0 -in 000005.ts -out 000005_out.ts` to decrypt the file but am not able to play it."*

Try as:

```
ffmpeg -decryption_key ef004a33ab60b5c5669f319072fb45a0 -i 000005.ts -codec copy -out 000005_out.ts
```

If that does not then there is a problem with your decryption key (make sure you're using the right one and nothing like a "time limit" is making it invalid.